# Wix project template for Visual Studio Express versions?

Tags: wix, wix3.6

Is it possible to use Wix with Express editions? I am interested in 2010/2012 versions. I know I can use candle and light from the command line, but I am interested in integration with IDE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Express versions of VS does not allow to extend the VS with the necessary plug-ins. So you have to stay with the command line.

Alternatively to VS you could try WiXEdit.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, if the goal is to have a free installer suite, WiX is perfectly happy installing into [Visual Studio Shell Integrated](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb129445.aspx), which is freely available. All features of WiX are available.

The only limitation is you have to open a different instance of Visual Studio in order to build your installer, but I haven't found this to be limiting in the slightest, and in fact I appreciate the separation of concerns.

Of course, another solution these days is to simply use VS Community Edition.