# Why does WiX not work in Visual Studio 2012 Express?

Tags: templates, visual-studio-2012, wix, windows-installer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Wix project template for Visual Studio Express versions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13218710/wix-project-template-for-visual-studio-express-versions)

Was looking for a free installer creator that integrates with Visual Studio 2012 Express. I have read great things about Windows Installer XML (WiX), but is seems like it won't work out of the box with the Express version of Visual Studio. Are there any work-arounds? I was wondering why a free and open-source capability wouldn't or couldn't support the project templates in the Express edition but can in all the others. Is this a built-in barrier from Microsoft to get people to upgrade?

Comment: The Express editions are very much meant to restrict you to poking around the framework with the developer experience Microsoft intends for it. Not as much for getting "real" work done.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Visual Studio Express does not support Extensibility by 3rd parties. This is a limitation Microsoft has placed on all the free editions of Visual Studio. Since Wix is being maintained as an open source project, it cannot integrate into Visual Studio Express as deep as it can into Visual Studio Professional and better.

You can still [call Wix from the command-line](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/using_custom_actions.htm) or through [WixEdit](http://wixedit.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: Which is a shame since if you install WiX on the free VS Int Shell redist it works just fine.

Comment: Yes, but Isolated/Integrated Shell doesn't support the standard project types either, so it really doesn't change anything. To get a version of Visual Studio that supports extensibility and at least one standard programming language, you need Visual Studio Professional or higher.

Comment: I think you missed my point.  It's a shame that Express can't do something that Shell can. If the feature set overlapped he wouldn't need Pro.  Then again, if he keeps his express projects in one solution and his WiX projects in another solution, he could use a VM to work on the wix and then send it all through TFS/MSBuild to compile.  Hack? Yes.  But it proves the point that the limitations are pointlessly annoying.

Comment: Yes, it seems you can't get free + free to cooperate very well, but $ + free works great. I understand MS' motivation, but still the older versions of Express could do simple setup projects. I am going to look into the WixEdit. Are there any other good, free wrappers with nice GUI front-ends?